# How to keep main Camel thread alive with Spring DSL

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel, middleware

I am developing my first real Camel-based Java app and am running into a bizarre, complicated issue that I *believe* is a result of the main Camel thread dying/finishing.

Basically, the route itself consists of just a few processors, and one of the processors does some heavy computations that take 20 - 25 seconds to finish. The app as a whole is terminating without throwing any exceptions/errors/log statements are any other indication that something went wrong, and is dying while doing these expensive computations.

I'm not looking for anybody to diagnose my problem, I just want a way to force the Camel route to stay alive, because what I *believe* is happening is that the main Camel thread is reaching the end of the route, stopping it, and shutting down the application. I'd like to force the main Camel thread to stay alive for, say, 60 seconds, to see if I can at least rule it out as a factor.

If using the Java DSL, I'd just throw the following on to the end of my route:

```
.to(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            // ...
        }
    }
})
.to("direct:endOfRoute");
```

I'm using Spring DSL (XML) - any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually, a spring context is alive until it's explicitly shut down and so is the camel context within. Try turn on debug logging to get an idea what's going on (what's shuting down your app).

Comment: Thanks @Petter (+1) - I understand this may be a red herring, but still, please humor me here...is there any way to force the main Camel thread to sleep for 60 seconds (via Spring DSL)?

Comment: Still not sure what you really want to achieve with this. But there is no specific spring DSL tag for sleep. Just make that processor above into a class, wire up a spring bean instance and ivoke that bean would be fairly simple. That's the way you do custom things in Spring DSL anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a route finishing will not terminate your Camel application/context, you just need to make sure that the container that instantiates the context keeps running...

see http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

that said, to your specific question, you can use the the [delayer EIP](http://camel.apache.org/delayer.html) to introduce an explicit delay in your route

Comment: That link is no longer available.